# Is it possible to use Google Sign-in without Javascript?

Tags: google-signin

I have an application where I'd been asked to support Google sign-in. Something we've tried to do since the beginning was not *require* javascript for any important functions. Is it possible to perform Google Sign-in without requiring Javascript?

I've read some of the guides such as https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in and https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth, but they all seem to have a javascript component involved.

For example, can we use only links and redirects, etc. to accomplish a Google-based authentication, along with some server-side verification?

Comment: It definitively is possible to do so (take a look at [HWI Oauth bundle](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle) ), but I think telling us what programming language you use could prove useful.

Comment: I didn't think the implementation language would matter all that much, since OAuth is theoretically all HTTP(S). I happen to be using Java on the back-end.

Comment: Ironically, SO doesn't work with javascript disabled. This is still a relevant question I think. When redirecting to Google for the OpenId Connect login, with javascript disabled, I'm redirected to this page saying the function I'm looking for requires javascript: https://accounts.google.com/o/noscript. Are there any OpenID Connect providers advertising html/css-only APIs?

Comment: @WeakPointer I can say from current experience that Facebook browser login flow works without JavaScript. If Google does not, that's unfortunate for JavaScript-disabled browsers and for headless automated testing.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want to do is described in the [OAuth 2.0 for Server-side Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer) documentation. Several of the sections in that doc have tabs with language specific examples and there is also an HTTP/REST tab that shows how to generically use Google's OAuth URls.

You will also want to follow [Google's sign-in branding guidelines](https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines).

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for the same thing. I'm sick of popups and I don't want them in my site. It seems like there should be a way to just link to a Google page, then redirect the user back to my site. However there doesn't seem to be any documentation about how to do that.

I also agree that it shouldn't matter what programming language is being used. Google doesn't need to know that. All we need is a URI to send the user to, and some way to indicate where the user should be redirected back to.